# Generate parentheses solution

Tags: python, recursion, combinatorics, balanced-delimiters

I have coded a solution to build all valid permutations of parentheses.

My code is below.

I have a question on my code based on a comment by my PEP8 checker. It said that there was no need to include the line `return` anywhere in the code (initially I included one). The solution works but I have never had a case using recursion where I didn't have to use the `return` line in the base-case.

How come I don't need it here?

The following expression initially had a `return` statement but I was told this was obsolete.

```
    if number_open == number_pairs and number_closed == number_pairs:
        print(output)
        build_parentheses.counter += 1
        return
```

Python 3.7 code:

```
"""Module builds all valid permutations of n parentheses
For example: n = 3:
    ((()))
    (()())
    (())()
    ()(())
    ()()()
Total = 5
"""


def build_parentheses(number_pairs: int,
                      output="",
                      number_open=0,
                      number_closed=0)-> str:
    """The function that builds the parentheses. Output as a string:
        number_pairs: number of parentheses pairs user desired
        All other parameters are private
    """
    if number_open == number_pairs and number_closed == number_pairs:
        print(output)
        build_parentheses.counter += 1
    else:
        if number_open < number_pairs:
            output += "("
            build_parentheses(number_pairs, output, number_open + 1, number_closed)
            output = output[:-1]
        if number_closed < number_open and number_open:
            output += ")"
            build_parentheses(number_pairs, output, number_open, number_closed + 1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    build_parentheses.counter = 0
    build_parentheses(5)
    print(f"=========\n{build_parentheses.counter} solutions")
```

By comparison, in [this post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/221554/print-the-string-equivalents-of-a-phone-number) I made, I did use the return statement.

Comment: At which line did you originally include the `return` statement?

Comment: After the line ```build_parentheses.counter += 1``` in the base-case ```if....```

Comment: Do you happen to have a code snippet where you did in fact needed to use the `return`statement? This way, we can compare that code with your current snippet.

Comment: Sorry. Yes. The following post I made on code-review is a nice comparison. 

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/221554/print-the-string-equivalents-of-a-phone-number

Comment: The key difference is you are using an `else:` block here, rendering the `return`obsolete.

Comment: I see. So because I reach the end of an ```if``` statment, does it automatically ```return```?

Comment: No, but because all remaining code in the function is in the `else`, there is no more reachable code detected. If you have more questions about the scope of code blocks, take it to chat :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94780/discussion-between-dfhwze-and-eml).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117251/what-should-be-done-with-questions-that-have-been-self-resolved-as-a-comment-ins) I'll provide a short answer to summarize what we discussed. A `return` statement only impacts code that short-circuits any remaining code that would have been called if omitted.

*pseudo code snippets below*

The `return` statement here skips snippet 2.

```
if (condition) {
  // .. snippet 1
  return;
}
// snippet 2
```

The `return` statement here is unnecessary.

```
if (condition) {
  // .. snippet 1
  return;
} else {
  // snippet 2
}
```

Comment: in the second snippet I would say the `else` is unnecessary. It allows you to arrange the rest of the code with 1 less level of indentation

Comment: @MaartenFabré You are correct. But these snippets are just trivial examples to show the purpose of the `return` statement.

Answer (score 3):

#### Effects

This is my main complaint about your code. `build_parentheses` prints out its results, but it would be cleaner for it to return them as a list, or yield them.

#### `.counter`

Using the attribute `build_parenthesis.counter` like this is technically fine, but it's really strange. I don't feel that ad-hoc attributes are particularly Pythonic, especially for functions. Also, `.counter` will not be needed if `build_parentheses` returns a list as suggested.

#### Names

I'd recommend `X_count` rather than `number_X`. It's mostly preference, though.

#### Public API

Since the `number_open` and `number_closed` parameters are not part of the public API, I'd recommend removing them. Make `build_parentheses` take only one parameter, `number_pairs`. It will call, and return the results of, `build_parentheses_aux`, an auxiliary/helper function, which takes `number_pairs` as well as several private/internal parameters.

#### Chained comparisons

`number_open == number_pairs and number_closed == number_pairs` may be written as `number_open == number_closed == number_pairs`. Generally, Python interprets chained comparisons as if they were combined with `and`. Two comparisons `A` and `B` applied to three variables `x`, `y`, and `z` like `x A y B z` is the same as writing `x A y and y B z`.

#### Everything else looks good

Style is generally good, though a space to the left of `-> str` would be nice; `and number_open` rather than `and number_open != 0` is Pythonic; `if __name__ == "__main__"` guard is good; `snake_case` is good; you have a docstring, ...

#### Suggested Code

Here is your code, with all suggestions implemented:

```
def build_parentheses(pair_count: int) -> str:
    """The function that builds the parentheses. Output as a string:
        pair_count: number of parentheses pairs user desired
    """
    return build_parentheses_aux(pair_count, 0, 0)

def build_parentheses_aux(pair_count: int,
                      open_count,
                      closed_count)-> str:
    """Auxiliary build_parentheses function.
        pair_count: number of parentheses pairs
        open_count: number of open parens so far
        closed_count: number of closed parens so far
    """
    if open_count == closed_count == pair_count:
        return [""]
    else:
        result = []
        if open_count < pair_count:
            for r in build_parentheses_aux(pair_count, open_count + 1, closed_count):
                result.append("(" + r)
        if closed_count < open_count and open_count:
            for r in build_parentheses_aux(pair_count, open_count, closed_count + 1):
                result.append(")" + r)
        return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    options = build_parentheses(5)
    print("\n".join(options) + f"\n=========\n{len(options)} solutions")
```

If you are familiar with generators, you could also write `build_parentheses_aux` as a generator, which would look cleaner (but may be less efficient).

Comment: I would skip the auxiliary function, and make `0` the default arguments for `open_count` and `closed_count`

Comment: @EML You're welcome! @Maarten Fabré I don't agree; `open_count` and `closed_count` aren't a part of the public API, so they shouldn't be in the API function

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for a return statement here because when you reach the end of a function, there is an implicit return.

For example:

```
1 def exampleFunction():
2   if someCondition:
3     doThis()
4   else:
5     doTheOtherThing()
6
```

We could put a return statement after the call to `doThis()`, but this would make no difference to the execution of the code. When `someCondition` is `True`, we enter that code block and then call `doThis()`. Then, we go to line 6 and implicitly return from the function.

So after executing line 3, we jump to line 6 and implicitly return, so explicitly returning after line 3 makes no difference.